# My LAMP running on virtual machine is not as fast as XAMPP

Tags: magento, ubuntu, xampp, virtualbox

I set Ubuntu Server 12.04 on the box running Apache 2 and PHP-FPM 5.5. My host OS is Ubuntu too and I have also a XAMPP with a similar LAMP stack.

Running a Magento store on it I get slower results than running the same application on XAMPP. On virtual machine the store loads in 5.5 seconds, and in XAMPP only ~0.3 second.

All things on the virtual machine are slower than on XAMPP.

I have my PHP files in a Virtualbox shared folder.

I've searched a lot but I don't find anything to help me.

Why is the reason for it?

Comment: I'd remove Magento from the equation and start with a simple PHP file.

Comment: I've tried using PHP files containing only phpinfo(). The performances are quite similar (the virtual machine is a very little more slow in this case). Wordpress is fast in both, too. Only Magento has a huge difference of performance.